# Load csv creates empty relationship type in db.schema

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I`m importing relationship data into my DB. Nodes have already been Imported before.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM " file:///Projekt_Strat_Massnahme.csv" AS line 
MERGE (a:Projekt {UID: toInteger(line.Projekt_UID)})
MERGE (b:Strategische_Massnahme {UID: 
toInteger(line.Strategische_Massnahme_UID)})
CREATE (a)-[:BETRIFFT]->(b)
```

Afterwards, a additional relationship type between (:Strategische_Massnahme) and (:Strategische_Massname) is created what makes no sense to me.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You have a lot of relationships that do not seem to be created by the query you show. Are you sure that some other query did not create the unexpected relationship?

Comment: I definitly can trace the issue to the Cypher statement above, since the Relationship is not there, before the statement. On the other hand, if I just create a new Graph only with [:Strategische Massnahmen] and [:Projekt] and commit the statement, the relationship does not appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`db.schema` can report relationships that do not actually exist. This is actually an open neo4j issue (see [Issue #9726](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/9726)) that has existed for a long time, but not yet fixed.

You should use [apoc.meta.graph](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_meta_graph) instead, since that does not have this bug.

Answer (score 0):

Nodes can have multiple labels, So if their is a node that is both a "Projekt" and "Strategische_Massnahme", and you draw a relationship to a "Strategische_Massnahme" node, that would create the extra loop (or other scheme links that you did not directly match)

If you feel this should be an invalid connection, than simply query for it, and decide if you should delete it. I recommend looking at the data to see what happened before deleting anything.

```
MATCH (a:Strategische_Massnahme)-[r:BETRIFFT]->(b:Strategische_Massnahme)
RETURN * //DELETE r if appropriate
```

Comment: Thanks, altough your Query gives my a empty result for *, however the relationship is still shown in the db.schema despite no such relationship exists between nodes.